# bash- can't change lines in file

Tags: bash, awk

I have to columns in a file. One is the name of a value, and the other is the corresponding value. I want to change the value assigned to specific names. So i have
Infile:

```
TB           10
Abs(M_1)          100
```

Ive tried this to (unsuccesfully) change it:

```
M1_0=$(grep "Abs(M_1)" $infile)
awk '{ gsub("$M1_0", "Abs(M_1)           $M1") };{print}' $infile > $infile.new
mv $infile.new $infile
```

Where I've defined M1 to be different every iteration.I don't get any errors but the file value doesn't change. I've tried dozens of sed configurations too. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You never closed that `$(` from line 1...

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. If I hadn't closed it, bash would complain.

Comment: `M1_0= $(grep ...)` is wrong. You have a space after `=`. Check with http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Sorry that's a typo as well. The situation is complicated and I can't copy paste this. So I had to type it out by hand on my phone. The space is not there. I had previously run it through shellcheck as well.

Comment: is inline file tab delimited?

Comment: Come back when you can test your code before posting. I'm voting to close this Q.

Comment: I can test the code. I can't copy paste it.

Comment: Tabs do not make a difference.

Comment: So you can't test the code you post. My point exactly.

Comment: I can type exactly as I have it there. Look if you don't have any suggestions please stop. I'm pretty desperate here. I've struggled an obscene amount of hours on code that should be quite simple.

Comment: @RogerRoglans: I had a suggestion, but you weren't listening ;)

Answer (score 0):

use `sed` instead:

*to create new file:*

```
sed "s/$M1_0/Abs(M_1)           $M1/g" $infile > $infile.new
```

---

*to save in same file ( this will elinimate `mv` step from your script):*

```
sed -i "s/$M1_0/Abs(M_1)           $M1/g" $infile
```